# Finding sum in all rows with R

Tags: r, apply

I have two vectors

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,6,6)
y <- c(1,1,2,3,4,2,2,4,4,4,3,3,1,4,2,3,1,4,4,4,2,2,2,3,3)
```

I found the number of values for each x (from 1 to 6) as

```
 t=table(x,y)
```

and get the table with 6 rows and 4 columns. Then I calculate the sum in all rows as `s=apply(t,1,sum)` and get the error. Could anybody explain what I do wrong?

Comment: `apply(t,1,sum)` works perfectly for me (see edits in your question). `rowSums(t)` gives the same results as before

Comment: Were you actually using a function called `tables` or was that a typo?

Comment: If you do `table(x,y)` and then `sum` the rows, aren't you just doing `table(x)`?

Answer (score 2):

What is the error? I don't get one with `apply(t, 1, sum)`. Try instead

```
rowSums(t)
##1 2 3 4 5 6 
##5 5 4 5 2 4
```

Or, you could simply use `table(x)`, which gives you exactly the same output.